# How to iterate an ObservableCollection of Dictionary in .Net Maui Page XML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, .net-maui

I have a data structure that comes from JSON:

```
{
"07-2022": [],
"08-2022": [
    {
        "event_title": "asdf"
        "positions": [
            {
                "position_title": "Graphics Op"
            },
            {
                "position_title": "Graphic Design"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"06-2023": []
}
```

I have models for the Job and Position

```
public class OpenJob {
    // props...
    public List<Position> positions { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I fetch the data and put it into a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<Models.OpenJob>> OpenJobList = new();

public async Task<Dictionary<string, List<Models.OpenJob>>> getOpenJobs() {
        if (OpenJobList?.Count > 0) {
            return OpenJobList;
        }
        var url = "https://api.com";
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            //Debug.WriteLine(response.ToString);
            OpenJobList = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, List<Models.OpenJob>>>();
        }
        return OpenJobList;
    }
```

Then In my ViewModel I transfer it to an ObservableCollection

```
//...
public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, List<OpenJob>>> OpenJobsCollection { get; } = new();
//...
try {
    IsBusy = true;
    var openJobs = await jobsService.getOpenJobs();
    
    if (OpenJobsCollection.Count > 0) {
        OpenJobsCollection.Clear();
    }
    OpenJobsCollection.Add(openJobs);
 }
```

Finally in my xml page I know how to iterate a simple List. But I can't find a solution for this data structure.

```
VerticalStackLayout>
    <CollectionView
        ItemsSource="{This Should be the Dictionary}"
        SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="THIS SHOULD BE THE STRING KEY">
                <Frame>
                    <CollectionView
                          ItemSource="{This should be the List of OpenJob Models}" />
                          <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models.OpenJob">
                                  <Label Text="{Binding event_title}"/>
                              </DataTemplate>
                          </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        
     </CollectionView>
    
    <Button Text="Get Open Jobs"
            Command="{Binding GetOpenJobsCommand}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
            />
    <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider if you REALLY need to nest CollectionViews. There are often better solutions, involving not scrollable layouts. I'll give you an example of this later.

You have three nested collections in your viewmodel (the `ObservableCollection`, the `Dictionary` and the `List<OpenJob>`), so be careful, because your first layout in the view has to bind the `ObservableCollection`, not the `Dictionary`.

Another suggestion I would give you is to use a custom class instead of `Dictionary`, because that allows to you to keep using `x:DataType`, while if you keep using Dictionaries you have to remove it, otherwise a compile-time error will be generated.

You can iterate over a Dictionary in xaml in this way:

```
<!-- D is the dictionary in your viewmodel -->
<!-- In your case it will be bound from the ObservableCollection -->

<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding D}"
    >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                >
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Key}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value}" />
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

If you really need to nest CollectionViews, you simply have to replace the outer `VerticalStackLayout` with another `CollectionView` and replace the `BindableLayout` tags with the classic ones.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. I am in the process of implementing now. Using a custom class sounds better. I guess i would make a "month" class that has a List of Jobs but being that the date string does not have a key I don't know how i would assign that value to the class.

Comment: This throws an error:Binding: Property "Key" not found on CS.ViewModel.OpenJobsViewModel"

Comment: @silversunhunter That's what I told you about the `x:DataType` tag. If you want to use the dictionary you have to remove that, because `Key` and `Value` are properties of `Dictionary`.

Comment: @silversunhunter you're having problems creating a custom class because your json has some keys that should be values (the months). If you can't change that structure, you could parse it as a `Dictionary`, like you're doing, and then iterate over the dictionary and convert it to a list of your custom class.