# How do I create a model from a JSON Key in C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have this JSON

```
{
"07-2022": [],
"08-2022": [
    {
        "event_title": "asdf",
        "positions": [
            {
                "position_title": "Graphics Op"
            },
            {
                "position_title": "Graphic Design"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"06-2023": []
}
```

it is a "month" key whose value is an array of objects that I call Job. Each job has an array of position objects.

so I can make those two models easily

```
public class Job {
    public string event_title {get;set;}
    public List<Position> positions {get; set;}
}

public class Position {
    public string position_title {get; set;}
}
```

**How do i get the date string into a month class that contains a List of Jobs?**

```
public class EventMonth {
    public string month {get; set;}
    public List<Job> jobs {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is not type of ```EventMonth``` this is ```Dictionary<string, List<Job>>```

Comment: `public string event_title {get;set;}` - I'd recommend to use proper C# naming convention and map to the json name via Attribute.

Comment: @Fildor doesnt it need to match the JSON for me to use automatic creation using ReadFromJsonAsync?

Comment: That's what the attributes do. You can name the properties whatever you like, as long as you put the correct attributes to them: [How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: @Fildor ahhh... I had no clue i could [JsonPropertyName("Wind")]! thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. It doesn't solve your actual problem, though.

Comment: @Fildor I am a noob so it is appreciated. my actual problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539260/how-to-iterate-an-observablecollection-of-dictionary-in-net-maui-page-xml/72543270#72543270 it was suggested that I create a custom class instead of using a dictionary. maybe i don't take that suggestion.

Comment: Yes, that suggestion has been given to you in regards to the UI Binding. In regards to the deserialization of the json, however, it's a Dictionary. That's what it is. But: You can do both. Deserialize to Dictionary and then "convert" to a List of a custom class. As Andrii is showing in his answer.

Comment: @silversunhunter edit your question. Because of missing "," after "asdf" your JSON is invalid. Must be ```"event_title": "asdf",```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your json is not type of `List<EventMonth>` but `Dictionary<string, List<Job>>` you need to implement model converting:

...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

...

```
public class Job
{
    [JsonProperty("event_title")]
    public string EventTitle {get;set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("positions")]
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }
}
public class Position 
{
    [JsonProperty("position_title")]
    public string PositionTitle { get; set; }
}
public class EventMonth 
{
    [JsonProperty("month")]
    public string Month { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("jobs")]
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var subResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Job>>>(jsonFromQuestion);
var result = subResult.Select(s => new EventMonth
{
    Month = s.Key,
    Jobs = s.Value
}).ToList();
```

EDIT: Same code but with using `System.Text.Json`

...

```
using System.Text.Json;    
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

...

```
public class Job
{
    [JsonPropertyName("event_title")]
    public string EventTitle {get;set;}
    
    [JsonPropertyName("positions")]
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }
}
public class Position 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("position_title")]
    public string PositionTitle { get; set; }
}
public class EventMonth 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("month")]
    public string Month { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("jobs")]
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var subResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<Job>>>(jsonFromQuestion);
var result = subResult.Select(s => new EventMonth
{
    Month = s.Key,
    Jobs = s.Value
}).ToList();
```

Comment: you can use JsonSerializer.Deserialize from System.Text.Json.

Comment: @AndriiKhomiak I think you don't even need the JsonProperty Attributes in class `EventMonth` since it is neither serialized to nor deserialized (directly) from JSON.

Comment: @Fildor I add them as reference to the original model property names

Comment: Ah, I see. Doesn't hurt, neither. I was just wondering.

Comment: @Fildor sorry, miss your first comment. I add example with ```System.Text.Json``` to the answer.

Comment: No problem. Adaption to System.Text shouldn't be an issue, really. But it's good work adding it. +1 well earned!

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, especially as it's likely you have no control over this. But in case you do, this a note to suggest the JSON is poorly structured (and fixing it could make your mapping much easier!)

You have this:

```
{
"07-2022": [],
"08-2022": [
    {
...
```

This is an object with properties named after month keys. Each property entry then includes an array of objects.

A better way to structure this JSON is as a dictionary, more like this:

```
[
 {
    "monthKey":"2022-07-01",
    "events":[]
 },
 {
    "monthKey":"2022-08-01",
    "events":[
      {
         ...
```

That is, we start with an array, since that is really what the entries are. Each item in the array is an object with a property `monthKey`, to tell us about the items. This key is built in a way that will make it easier to create a full date object representing the first date of the month. The array objectys also have an "events" array.

In this way we more accurately communicate the meta data about the events, and we do it such that it's easier to model for languages that don't allow property names with only digits.

As an additional note, nowhere in the sample is there ever more than one event in the month. This is likely incidental to the sample data, but if not we should also consider changing the `events` property into a object, instead of an array.